# Formula to substitute dataframe column names with categories defined in a second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, names

Let's say I have data in wide format (samples in row and species in columns).

```
species <- data.frame(
    Sample = 1:10, 
    Lobvar = c(21, 15, 12, 11, 32, 42, 54, 10, 1, 2), 
    Limtru = c(2, 5, 1, 0, 2, 22, 3, 0, 1, 2), 
    Pocele = c(3, 52, 11, 30, 22, 22, 23, 10, 21, 32), 
    Genmes = c(1, 0, 22, 1, 2,32, 2, 0, 1, 2)
)
```

And I want to automatically change the species names, based on a reference of functional groups that I have for all of the species (so it works even if I have more references than actual species in the dataset), for example:

```
reference <- data.frame(
    Species_name = c("Lobvar", "Ampmis", "Pocele", "Genmes", "Limtru", "Secgio", "Nasval", "Letgos", "Salnes", "Verbes"), 
    Functional_group = c("Crustose", "Geniculate", "Erect", "CCA", "CCA", "CCA", "Geniculate", "Turf","Turf", "Crustose"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Dan Y suggestions, I can now changes the species names to their functional group names:

```
names(species)[2:ncol(species)] <- reference$Functional_group[match(names(species), reference$Species_name)][-1]
```

However, in my actual data.frame I have more species, and this creates many functional groups with the same name in different columns. I now would like to sum the columns that have the same names. I updated the example to give a results in which there is more than one functional group with the same name.

So i get this:

```
Sample Crustose CCA Erect CCA Crustose
      1       21   2     3   1        2
      2       15   5    52   0        3
      3       12   1    11  22        4
      4       11   0    30   1        1
      5       32   2    22   2        0
      6       42  22    22  32        0
```

and the final result I am looking for is this:

```
Sample Crustose CCA Erect
  1       23      3     3     
  2       18      5    52    
  3       16     22    11       
  4       12      1    30       
  5       32      4    22       
  6       42     54    22
```

How do you advise on approaching this? Thanks for your help and the amazing suggestions I already received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re Q1) We can use `match` to do the name lookup:

```
names(species)[2:ncol(species)] <- reference$Functional_group[match(names(species), reference$Species_name)][-1]
```

Re Q2) Then we can `mapply` the `rowSums` function after some regular expression work on the colnames:

```
namevec <- gsub("\\.[[:digit:]]", "", names(df))
mapply(function(x) rowSums(df[which(namevec == x)]), unique(namevec))
```

Comment: That is brilliant! thanks! (also thanks for the edits and corrections to my question)

Comment: So it works, but what if then i want to sum all the Functional groups columns with the same name?

Comment: `rowSums(species[grep("same_name", names(species))])`

Comment: No that does not work for me, it gives a row with all zeros.
rowSums(species[grep("same_name", names(species))])
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

What i would like is to have a final data.frame which have the sum of all the functional groups data. We successfully got to change the names, but i am stuck in summing all columns with the same name. I found some solution by converting to long format and then again to wide, but I was wondering whether there is a quicker way...

Comment: So in my previous comment, you actually have to put in the colname where I wrote "same_name" (e.g., you write "Crustose" instead of "same_name").  However, this only works for one name at a time.  See my edited answer above for how to do sum columns with the same name, and to do so for all the different colnames.

Comment: That works like a charm! Thanks. A final question: I am reading about gsub()

so the "\\.[[:digit:]]" part is a combination of different regular expression syntax... what does it mean? take any character (\\.) in an hexadecimal form (a b c d etc.) ?

Comment: The `gsub` command is saying to replace "a period followed by a number" with a blank in the character vector of rownames for `df`